# Can we have the option to review the question too, when an answer appears in /review

Tags: feature-request, review

I often come across answers in `/review`, where the question it's answering needs more fixing/closing/downvoting than the answer itself. Consider these two examples:

[image]
[image]

I don't know jQuery to actually "fix" the answer in the first one or wrap some explanatory text around the code. However, upon dragging down the bar to reveal the question, I saw parts of it that needed fixing. As for the second, I was about to flag it as "Not an answer", when I realized that it *is* in fact, an answer to the question. The problem was with the question, which should've never been allowed to be asked.

Right now, there's no option to do anything to the question from within that page. As I understand, the option to reveal the question is there so as to provide some context to the answer being reviewed. It would be nice though, if we could fix the question right there instead of having to open it in a new tab. Can we have this feature, pretty please?

Comment: /me tries scripting it

Comment: @Manishearth: All I can manage is a script that gives a working edit button--and it opens a new page anyway :/ . SE JS is obfuscated, so I can't go deep and make a working example.

Comment: @Manishearth Thanks for trying, but I think it needs to be a dev job, because I'd like integration with other `/review` features — specifically, I'd like reviews on these to also be tracked and accounted for

Comment: Yeah. Too bad SE isn't open-source :/